# "phonegap run android" phonegap 3 under windows can't build a project

Tags: android, windows, node.js, cordova

I 'm trying to create a new project with phonegap3 :-
 I set up the dev environment that include

- node.js
- Ant
- Android SDK

and they all updated to the last versions 
after creating the project , I get the directory for project:
EX :

```
     phonegap create HelloWorld com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

but the main problem that I can't add the android platform to it

with the 3 comands as follow :-

trying to "phonegap add platform android"/"phonegap build android"/"phonegap run android"

I also installed throw the node the "cordova" and the same problem exists when I replace the phonegap with cordova !

```
     Users\koko\test\www>phonegap build android
     [ponegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
     [ponegap] using the local environment
     [onegap] adding the Android platform...
     [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

     Users\koko\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
             throw e;
                   ^
     Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
      at C:\Users\koko\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
      at _rejected (C:\Users\koko\.cordova\lib\android\cordova
      .........
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I also uninstall the node and re-download it and the problem still exists !
I viewed many questions with people around this issue but I don't know where exactly the error ! 
I wish to see the project running inside the emulator !

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that cordova failed to execute following command in shell:

```
>android list target
```

Why don't you try to execute it manually? It may produce more information about this problem.

Didn't you forget to add following folders to your PATH?

- android-sdk/tools
- android-sdk/platform-tools

**EDIT:**

The latest android SDK has different folder structure. note the "sdk" folder.

- android-sdk/sdk/tools
- android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply but How to execute it manually "android list target" I've looked up for it and seem to be @ debugging and running the code manully from the eclipse , how it would effect my case that I write from the node command line ?                                         I have checked for <ul><li>    android-sdk/tools </li><li>
    android-sdk/platform-tools</li> and they are correctly configured !

Comment: I meant operaring system shell. You know, Windows command promt, or Linux shell. Cordova tries to execute there command I'm talking about and fails.

Comment: The latest android sdk has different folder layout. android-sdk/sdk/tools

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have set the following system variables:

`ANT_HOME = path to ant files
JAVA_HOME = path to java JDK (NOT JRE!!)
ANDROID_HOME = path to android sdk`

After that, you have to add

- %ANT_HOME%\bin
- %JAVA_HOME%\bin
- %ANDROID_HOME%\bin

to your PATH variable.

If it still doesnt work, make sure you have the Google USB Driver installed (this took me hours to find and fix -.-)